# Host Controller vs Interface Vs Connector

Tags: ssd

Host controller, interface, connector. Yes, connector is pretty obvious but what does host controller and interface mean in the context of SSDs?

Answer (score 1):

If you have something more specific, I'd be happy to help answer a more detailed question.

**Host Controller** - chip on the motherboard that allows the storage drive to talk to the cpu.

**Interface** - Think of it as how the ssd is being connected to the machine. Depending on speed/bandwidth requirements, this can be different things. A standard laptop 2.5" SATA SSD's interface would be SATA. Some of the newer, smaller machines use M.2 nvme. If you had a USB flash drive, (technically ssd), it's interface would be USB.

**Connector** - The connector goes hand in hand with the interface. Each type of interface will take a different connector. USB drive take USB, 2.5" ssd will usually use a sata connector, etc.

Comment: Narzard, thanks! Is there a difference between M.2 or NVMe or is NVMe the consortium who invented the M.2 standard? Re: the Host Controller, are most of these backwards compatible? For example, a S-ATA disk will use AHCI right and will also work with IDE? Most modern SSDs with an M.2 use PCIe host controller right? Is PCIe backwards compatible with AHCI?